# Cross thread exception from minimized winform app

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a FileSystemWatcher that is waiting for files to appear in a folder, which then triggers an insert to an ObservableCollection.  When the form is open on the screen the update happens successfully.  But when the form is minimized I get a cross-thread exception?  I know I can just check for context, but I want to know why this behaviour is happening so I can ensure it doesn't come up again in other places.

I've tried this with a new blank winform app, and it errors 100% of the time whether it is minimised or not, so I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong or how to diagnose the issue.  The main app is thousands of lines long, with many custom libraries so I can't post all of it here.

Called by the watcher

```
    private void CheckForFiles(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        WaitingFiles.Add(e.FullPath);
    }
```

Which triggers this

```
    private async void WaitingFiles_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentProcessStatusLabel.Text = "Checking download for despatch file";
    }
```

When I minimize the window I run the following code;

```
Hide();
SysTrayIcon.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Unless a [SynchronizingObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.synchronizingobject?view=net-5.0) is set, events are raised on a background thread, and background threads are not allowed to update the UI. I'm not sure why it works unless the application is minimized, but a good start is to ensure you are using correct synchronization to avoid issues like this.

If you want to update the UI you should either set the SynchronizingObject to one of the controls in your UI, or manually schedule any UI updates to the UI thread.